# What are the costs of using Double Slice?

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e-playtest

I'm a bit confused about the double slice feat.  Does it now cost 1 or 2 actions to use it? And what are the penalties now when you use it with agile and non-agile weapons?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Both attacks are at the same penalty

**Double Slice** (Fighter feat) costs two actions, allows you to make two attacks with the standard modifiers, and combine their damage and enhancements before applying resistances or damage reduction of your target.

The feat also mentions that the offhand takes -2 if it isn't a weapon with the *Agile* trait, which normally means -4 then -8 instead of -5 then -10 for making multiple attacks. This penalty is in addition to whatever penalty you would take already, as explained on page 305:

> Striking multiple times has diminishing returns. The multiple attack penalty applies to attacks after the first, whether those attacks are Strikes, special attacks like the grapple use of the Athletics skill, or attacks from spells.

But note that those two attacks are actually a single **Strike** action, and the ability says that they are *"with each of your two melee weapons, each at your **current multiple attack penalty**"*.

So this leaves us with two situations:

- offhand is agile: first attack +0, second attack +0.
- offhand is not agile: first attack +0, second attack -2.

And if you happen to have made a Strike on your first action, then proceed to Double Slice with your second and third actions, it will go as follows:

- offhand is agile: first attack -5, second attack -5.
- offhand is not agile: first attack -5, second attack -7.

If you use all 3 actions on attacking you either end up with (0/0)/-10 or 0/(-5/-5), assuming the offhand is agile.

Comment: I'd note that the feat specifies that both attacks are made "at your current multiple attack penalty", so the second wouldn't take the -4/-7, it'd be at the exact same penalty as the first (outside of the -2 for non-agile).

Comment: @Delioth I did some more research, your interpretation was correct.

Comment: That last line is incorrect.  If both weapons are agile, you get (0/0)/-8.  or 0/(-4/-4).  If both are non-agile, you get (0/-2)/-10 or 0/(-5/-7).  if only the offhand is agile, then you'd get 0/(-5/-4) or (0/0)/-10 or (0/0)/-8 depending on which weapon you used where.

Comment: @BenBarden this was answered during the playtest, this answer is no longer valid for the current version of the rules. I honestly thought those questions would be purged after a while.

Answer (score 0):

## 1 action

Page 296 of the Playtest Rulebook says:

> An activity might cause you to take specific actions. You don’t have to spend additional actions to perform them because they’re already factored into the activity’s required actions. (See Dependant Abilities.)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already.